# Is there an efficient way to use pandas row values to perform `str.count` on another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have the dataframe final that I constructed in the following way -

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = ['mechanical@engineer plays with machines','field engineer works with oil pumps','lab_scientist trains a rat that plays the banjo','doctor kills patients',
        'computer-engineer creates killing AI','scientist/engineer publishes nothing']# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job'])
final = df['Job'].str.split().explode().value_counts().reset_index()
final.columns = ['words', 'number']
print(final.head())
```

I also have another dataframe, `df_new` -

```
new_data = ['mechanical@engineer plays with machines while learning mechanics','field engineer works with oil pumps and gas cylinders','lab_scientist trains a rat',
             'doctor kills all','computer-engineer creates a conscious AI','scientist/engineer publishes something']# Create the pandas DataFrame]

df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Job'])
```

I'd like to count the number of times each word from the row words of the dataframe `final` appears in `df_new`.

Here's how I did it with a for loop -

```
final.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)
df_list = []
for index, row in final.iterrows():
    keyword_pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(row['words'])}\b"
    foo = df.Job.str.count(keyword_pattern).sum()
    df_list.append(foo)

final['new_col'] = df_list

print(final.head())
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it, perhaps without a for loop? I was expecting a similar post on SO regarding this, but couldn't find any.

Here is the entire code for convenience -

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = ['mechanical@engineer plays with machines','field engineer works with oil pumps','lab_scientist trains a rat that plays the banjo','doctor kills patients',
        'computer-engineer creates killing AI','scientist/engineer publishes nothing']# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job'])
final = df['Job'].str.split().explode().value_counts().reset_index()
final.columns = ['words', 'number']
print(final.head())

new_data = ['mechanical@engineer plays with machines while learning mechanics','field engineer works with oil pumps and gas cylinders','lab_scientist trains a rat',
             'doctor kills all','computer-engineer creates a conscious AI','scientist/engineer publishes something']# Create the pandas DataFrame]

df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Job'])

final.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)
df_list = []
for index, row in final.iterrows():
    keyword_pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(row['words'])}\b"
    foo = df.Job.str.count(keyword_pattern).sum()
    df_list.append(foo)

final['new_col'] = df_list
print(final.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join everything in one string and then use the method `count` of `str`:

```
entire_string = ','.join(df_new['Job'])
final['new_col'] = final['words'].apply(lambda x: entire_string.count(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module which supports [overlapping matches](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#overlapped-argument-for-regexfindall-and-regexfinditer).

This allows you to build a single pattern.

You can `.merge` the result back into `final`.

```
import regex

all_words = (re.escape(word) for word in final['words'])
all_words = (rf'\b{word}\b' for word in all_words)
all_words = regex.compile(f'''({'|'.join(all_words)})''')

counts = (
   df_new['Job']
      .map(lambda row: all_words.findall(row, overlapped=True))
      .explode().value_counts()
)

print(
   pd.merge(final, counts, how='left', left_on='words', right_on='Job')
)
```

```
                  words  number  new_col  count
0                  with       2        2    2.0
1                 plays       2        1    1.0
2   mechanical@engineer       1        1    1.0
3                   the       1        0    NaN
4             publishes       1        1    1.0
5    scientist/engineer       1        1    1.0
6                    AI       1        1    1.0
7               killing       1        0    NaN
8               creates       1        1    1.0
9     computer-engineer       1        1    1.0
10             patients       1        0    NaN
11                kills       1        1    1.0
12               doctor       1        1    1.0
13                banjo       1        0    NaN
14                 that       1        0    NaN
15                  rat       1        1    1.0
16                    a       1        2    2.0
17               trains       1        1    1.0
18        lab_scientist       1        1    1.0
19                pumps       1        1    1.0
20                  oil       1        1    1.0
21                works       1        1    1.0
22             engineer       1        4    4.0
23                field       1        1    1.0
24             machines       1        1    1.0
25              nothing       1        0    NaN
```